# ikiwiki on lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, ikiwiki

I am trying to install ikiwiki on a raspberry pi, which runs lighttpd.

I can create the wiki in my user's home but once I try to see it on the webserver (at the address+"~/username/wikiname"), it returns 404.

Linking the wiki directory to `/var/www` results in a 500 error.

I am doing something wrong or missing something?

As requested in the comments, here's my lighttpd.conf:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    #"mod_rewrite",
    "mod_fastcgi"
)

server.modules += ( "mod_scgi" )
scgi.server = (
            "/RPC2" =>
            ( "127.0.0.1" =>
              (
               "socket" => "/tmp/rpc.socket",
               "check-local" => "disable",
               "disable-time" => 0,  # don't disable scgi if connection fails
              )
            )
          )
fastcgi.server             = ( ".php" =>
                           ( "localhost" =>
                             (
                            "min-procs" => 1,
                            "max-procs" => 2,
                            "max-load-per-proc" => 4,
                            "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket",
                            "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php5-cgi"
                             )
                           )
                        )


server.document-root        = "/var/www" 
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80
index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

I also performed the steps highlighted here: http://ikiwiki.info/tips/dot_cgi/

Comment: What is your lighttpd configuration?

Answer (score 0):

the answer lies in the config file you posted. The line that contains:

```
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
```

this is blocking your url request, try removing the [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) from your config file.